Function to return a specific column from a table based on value
I have a query (PostgreSQL 15.4) like this:
Select p."prodId", p."prodDesc", p."areaName", x."location1" as "Location"
From ops."Products" p
Inner Join ops."Locations" x on p."prodId" = x."prodId" 
                             and p."areaName" = x."areaName1"

Here's the caveat: in the table Locations, there are three locations, location1, location2, and location3. In addition, there are three columns areaName1, areaName2, and areaName3.
I need to return the location column as either location1, location2, or location3, based on the column areaName in the Products table being equal to one of the corresponding areaName columns in Locations: areaName1, areaName2, or areaName3.
My thinking was to be able to use some sort of function where I could join the function to the rest of my query and have the function handle all of the above. In a land and time far away, I probably would've handled this as dynamic SQL, but wondering if there is a better way to go?

Please provide a [mre] including table DDL, sample data, and desired results. From the description, this appears to be a data modeling problem instead of a query problem. There is a hidden table, Areas, smeared across Locations and Products, screaming for it own existence. Consider revising the schema before expending effort on the query. The combination of areaName and location form a repeating group. Querying will be much easier with a normalized schema.

Consider changing the table and column identifiers to snake case instead of camel case. The need to quote camel case identifiers adds excessive visual noise which makes queries much more difficult to read.

You should change the locations table. Don't have the three (areaname, location) pairs in one row, have them in three rows.
You can do that inline in the query, but it will be slower (and less maintainable) than just fixing the data structure.
SELECT
  p."prodId",
  p."prodDesc",
  p."areaName",
  l."location"
FROM
  ops."Products"   p
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT "prodId", 1 AS rowid, "areaName1" AS "areaName", location1 AS location FROM ops."Locations"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "prodId", 2 AS rowid, "areaName2" AS "areaName", location2 AS location FROM ops."Locations"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "prodId", 3 AS rowid, "areaName3" AS "areaName", location3 AS location FROM ops."Locations"
)
  AS l
    ON  p."prodId"   = l."prodId" 
    AND p."areaName" = l."areaName";


This split might cause duplicates if any Location holds same areaname in more than one of areaName1, areaName2, areaName3. I agree a schema change might simplify things.

You can use a case to switch between them and an in/=any(array[]) to join on any one.
demo at db-fiddle
Select p."prodId"
     , p."prodDesc"
     , p."areaName"
     , case p."areaName" 
       when x."areaName1" then x."location1" 
       when x."areaName2" then x."location2" 
       when x."areaName3" then x."location3"
       end as "Location"
From ops."Products"  as p
Join ops."Locations" as x 
  on p."prodId"   =     x."prodId" 
 and p."areaName" in (  x."areaName1"
                      , x."areaName2"
                      , x."areaName3");




prodId
prodDesc
areaName
Location




1
prodDesc1
areaName1_1
Location1_1


2
prodDesc2
areaName2
Location2




That's awesome, and thank you. Gonna give that a shot today (after I plead with them to change the database of course).
